# Trouble understanding a command within the protr library

Tags: r

I am reading through documentation for an R library I am interested in utilizing and I came across something that I was confused by. The command is the following:

```
library("protr")

x <- readFASTA(system.file(
  "protseq/P00750.fasta",
  package = "protr"
))[[1]]

extractAAC(x)
```

Now I understand what the command does and I understand the different parts of the commmand. One of the things that I don't understand is the [[1]] section in the command.Is that just the number of fasta sequences?

Comment: The `[[` in R refers to indexing. It means "extract the first (since 1) value in that object". That value in itself could be anything from a scalar number to a whole data frame.

Comment: so would I need to erase that if I wanted to include all things within the fasta file assuming there were multiple sequences in said file?

Comment: Likely so. I'm not familiar with fasta files.